# Trying to learn JavaScript Map() object for keyword-value pairs

Tags: javascript, keyword-search

In the early 1990s working in C developing real time music software, I wanted to code a keyword lookup algorithm which I finally did in JavaScript years later. It was accepted to SourceForge as HashCompactor, and someone asked me where to find out more about it. Then the HTML5 Map object obfuscated it, and my buggy forgotten code fell to the wayside.

I've recently rewritten it as MyMap to better match the JavaScript Map object for porting to other languages as originally intended. (Most of the demo action is in console.log.) I seems to match the specifications as best I can, but there's quirks specific to JavaScript I can't duplicate, so I'm curious as to whether I can use `defineProperty` to do so, say, by toggling a size property size to be read-only to the client instead of a function call, and I saw something about `enumeration` that might fix issues with the missing MyMap functionality?

I don't understand the `defineProperty` function whatsoever.

Otherwise, my biggest concerns are with garbage collection. Should every parameter be explicitly deleted or just those allocated with new? Didn't I see an algorithm that deep cleans objects?

Otherwise, the premise of the code is to read each character in the keyword string or number creating children for those that come after it so that everything beginning with the same character or digit only searches that call tree.

https://SkewsMe.com/code/HashCompactor/MyMap.html

Comment: So what is your questions?

Comment: IE11 must die, or be ignored. Browser features here http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/

Comment: You can use a polyfill for IE.

Comment: You can use a transpiler for environments that don't support ES6 syntax.

Comment: I've never heard of polyfill except maybe 25 years ago in connection with graphics.

Comment: And transpilers sound fun. I seem to remember enjoying programs like LISP and HyperTalk. Wanted LISP to C, natural language libraries for HyperTalk.

Comment: @KevinCrosby it's only cool to a certain point to keep going on about stuff from 25 years ago

Comment: Is there a faster method of updating the Map's value than `mapTo.set(key,existing.concat(data))`? Array.concat and .push don't work the same way.

Comment: With the new FileReader() object, I don't have to use ActiveX anymore. Gotta fix for this patch job?

`while (head < size){    
      tail = filetext.indexOf('\n',head);
      if (tail != -1){
        eclf = new LogFormatExtended(filetext.slice(head,tail));
        add(map, eclf.clf.remotehost, eclf);
        this.count++;
      } else {
        eclf = new LogFormatExtended(filetext.slice(head));
        add(map, eclf.clf.remotehost, eclf);
        this.count++;
        break;
      }
      head = tail + 1;
    }
`

Comment: I know there's a bunch of interrelated stack___ sites. Is there a stackchat for random question answers among legitimate users? Stuff like where should I round off pi for 64-bit processors? We gamers used to use Ventrilo and Mumble.

Comment: If you have some data to try out your concat and add functions. Or a description of the data you would typically use. Ie how often does add encounter an existing key, same for concat, what is the usage share for the conditional braches

Comment: @ScottSelby Dredging up old dirt, most of society has totally forgotten about remote-controlled people back in the 1960s like the [Acoustic Kitty](https://facebook.com/AcousticKiddy) programs.

Comment: @Blindman67 - http://skewsme.com/webloghog.html is the code, but as of yet I don't have a Log Format file(s) I can supply for examples.

Comment: I have just been testing add generating random data using both small and large set of keys `doFor(1000,()=>add(map,randI(10),randI(10)));` and `doFor(1000,()=>add(map,randI(1000),randI(10)));`  (`doFor` is an iterator, `randI(n)` returns a random item of set of `n` items). Small sets are significantly quicker (no surprise) I tried refactoring in a variety of ways, nothing could improve on what you have, with one exception. If the key is a numeric hash (Number) then you get significant performance gain (50% faster for large set) using a map as array or object. eg `map = {}; if(map[key]).. etc`